# Protecting a directory from direct URL access

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

need some help...

I need to protect all the `FOLDERS` in a `DIRECTORY` from **direct `URL`** access. Can I do this with `.htaccess` and if yes, how? Or is their a safer method?

Here's my situation, I allow a user to UPLOAD a a pdf file.

The file is sent to `/uploads/{userid}/{filename}`

This all works dandy, but the issue is that the `PDF` can be accessed directly if someone knows the `{userid}` and `{filename}`

**I want to secure the `uploads` directory and all sub directories from direct URL access.**

At the same time however my database (MySQL) needs to be able to browse the `uploads` directory and sub directories to confirm that a PDF file was uploaded and let the admin download the file from the admin control panel.

Now I'm not asking you to write my code. I'm just letting you know my specs because I assume someone might suggest htpasswd but I don't think I can use that solution as per my requirements.

If you have a simple solution or if you can point me on the right track to a tutorial please do so.

Thanks!

Comment: safest option is to move the directory outside the web root.

Comment: I did but with the filename and userid you can access the PDF

Comment: that's **not** outside the web root then

Comment: the root is /site  the pdf is in /site/uploads/{useridhash}/file.pdf   That isn't in root to my understanding of root. If i'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: Under /site is root to my understanding...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14253/discussion-between-fabio-anselmo-and-dagon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Fabio points out - it's better to keep such files out of web root. But you still CAN use .htaccess to protect the files. They'll be guaranteed protected unless you accidentally delete the .htaccess or the sysadmin changes the main configuration (which sometimes happens).

Just put a an .htaccess into the directory you want to protect, and put a single line in that .htaccess:

```
deny from all
```

Comment: when i add this line, it block access from within the server.