# How to protect assets folder file from direct url access in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url

Can we protect file from assets folder from direct url access
I use codeigniter 2.1.2, my structure is

- application
- assets
- -images
- --image1.jpg
- --image2.jpg
- system

I want protect image1.jpg from direct url access, but can use in view
Maybe other people says that this question is duplicate, but I'm not found the spesific question from other people to protect the folder and file but still access the file from views in codeigniter
Thank you for your help

It's done by @hrishi answer

I add .htaccess to images folder then add this code

```
SetEnvIf Referer mydomain.com internal
#
<Files *>
order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=internal
</Files>
```

Comment: check this answer. May be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603801/protecting-a-directory-from-direct-url-access

Comment: Add .htaccess with line
deny from all
can protect file from direct url, but my app can't use the the file to show in view, I still need to show image in view from protected folder, Can I?

Comment: Try deny from all and  then Allow from your url

Comment: Thanks @hrishi It was working in my website I add .htaccess and add this code 
    SetEnvIf Referer mydomain.com internal 
    # 
    <Files *> 
    order Deny,
    Allow Deny from all 
    Allow from env=internal 
    </Files>